# emacs vc-print-log show all git commits

Tags: git, emacs

I have a problem with them emacs `vc-print-log` function, it doesn't always show what I want to see.

## Setup

```
# Initialize a folder with 3 bogus files (a, b and c)
$ mkdir rep && cd rep
$ echo a>a ; echo b>b ; echo c>c

# Initialize a git repository with 3 bogus commits (a, b and c)
$ git init .
$ git add a && git commit -m 'a'
$ git add b && git commit -m 'b'
$ git add c && git commit -m 'c'
```

The head is now on `c`. I can move the head back to do some regression testing:

```
# Check out an older revision
$ git checkout HEAD~1
```

The head is now on `b`, but I can still view the commit `c` using this command-line:

```
$ git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph
* 6d269bf (master) c
* f75259d (HEAD) b
* aa89842 a
```

## With Emacs

When I'm using emacs, I often use the key binding `C-x v l` (`vc-print-log`) to view all the changes to a file. But if I use `vc-print-log` on the `rep` directory then it only show me commits `a` and `b`, not `c`.

```
*  (HEAD)f75259d..: Oli L 2017-12-01 b
* aa89842..: Oli L 2017-12-01 a

Show 2X entries    Show unlimited entries
-UUU:%%--F1  *vc-change-log*   All (4,41)     (Git-Log-View from rep) ---------
```

Is there a way to view all commits in emacs?

Thanks :)